# JQuery retrieving id from Checkbox at run time

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is, I want to retrieve checkbox id at runtime and use them later for other purpose. 
But retrieved id is read as object.

My Code is:

```
 // Following code gives id of checkbox which contains myCheckbox as its id.

   var myCheckbox= $('input[id$=myCheckbox]')[0].id;

 //  and Now I want to check if that checkbox is checked with following code:


  if ($(myCheckbox).is(':checked')) 
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
```

But here myCheckbox id is read as Object instead of id and thus always enter in else condition and returns 0. This code works when I enter id of checkbox directly.

```
if ($('#ctl001_myCheckbox').is(':checked')) 
        return 1;
      else 
        return 0;
```

It shouldnot be so complicated, I have been working with Javascript but new to JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the ID correctly, but the jQuery selector requires the `#` symbol, much in the same way as a CSS selector does. You need to add the `#` character to your selector:

```
if ($('#'+myCheckbox).is(':checked')) 
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

BenM is correct, but why are you getting the ID of the element, and then look it up *again*? You already found the element, there is no need to search for it a second time.

Just keep a reference to the element:

```
var myCheckbox = $('input[id$=myCheckbox]').first();
// or var myCheckbox = $('input[id$=myCheckbox]')[0];

// and later 

if (myCheckbox.is(':checked')) { 
// or if (myCheckbox.checked) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
return  (($('#' + myCheckbox).is(':checked')) ^ false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
var myCheckbox= $('input[id$=myCheckbox]').attr('id');
```

Comment: He is using the DOM element, by referencing the first element in the array.